# Remove all constraints from a table oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, foreign-keys

**Guys my question is I don't know the constraint names that I've added to a table. But I need to remove or disable all those foreign key constraints. But how?**

```
SQL> desc orders;


Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ORDER_ID                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
 PRODUCT_ID                                         VARCHAR2(10)
 DATE_OF_ORDER                                      TIMESTAMP(6)
 CUST_ID                                            VARCHAR2(10)
 QUANTITY                                           NUMBER(38)
 TOTAL_PRICE                                        FLOAT(10)
 DELIVERY_STATUS                                    VARCHAR2(10)
```

Answer (score 4):

The related foreign constraints might be determined by using `user_constraints` dictionary view, and you can disable the foreign key constraint of this table by the following code block

```sql
BEGIN
  FOR c IN
    (
      SELECT * 
        FROM user_constraints c
       WHERE c.constraint_type = 'R'
         AND c.table_name = 'ORDERS')
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||c.table_name||
                      ' DISABLE CONSTRAINT '||c.constraint_name;
  END LOOP;
END;  
/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a tool like sql developer you can just right click the table name in the navigator and select constraint > disable all or drop